# Printing an ArrayList<HashMap>

Tags: java

The following is a program i wrote in java to print an ArrayList but when i print the array list i get the same map printed over and over again. should i try using another type of data stucture to print it. If i dont find a proper method I thougt I'll use a POJO class.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> alist = new ArrayList<String>();
        nlist.add("Mich");
        nlist.add("Aud");
        alist.add("22");
        alist.add("20");
        HashMap<String,String> response = new HashMap<String,String>();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> responseList = new      ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        for(int i=0; i< nlist.size(); i++){
        response.put("Name",nlist.get(i));
        response.put("Age",alist.get(i));
        responseList.add(response);
        }
        System.out.println("Result="+responseList);
     }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Result=[{Age=20 , Name=Aud},{Age=20 , Name=Aud}]
```

Comment: You are only calling `println()` once, so I don't see how you getting anything printed "over and over again."  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: You are adding the same `HashMap` instance multiple times to your List. Move `HashMap<String,String> response = new HashMap<String,String>();` into your loop.

Comment: This kind of question comes up so frequently there ought to be some canonical answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move the initialization of the `HashMap` inside the `for` loop. The current code overrides the keys in the same map.

Answer (score 0):

Please declare `HashMap<String,String> response = new HashMap<String,String>();` inside the `for-loop` as follows:

```
for(int i=0; i< nlist.size(); i++){
 HashMap<String,String> response = new HashMap<String,String>();
 response.put("Name",nlist.get(i));
 response.put("Age",alist.get(i));
 responseList.add(response);
}
```

After the above changes, the output is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `response` for each iteration of the loop

```
    for(int i=0; i< nlist.size(); i++){
       HashMap<String,String> response = new HashMap<String,String>();

       response.put("Name",nlist.get(i));
       response.put("Age",alist.get(i));
       responseList.add(response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine:

```
ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> alist = new ArrayList<String>();
        nlist.add("Mich");
        nlist.add("Aud");
        alist.add("22");
        alist.add("20");

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> responseList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nlist.size(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>();
            response.put("Name", nlist.get(i));
            response.put("Age", alist.get(i));
            responseList.add(response);
        }
        System.out.println("Result=" + responseList);
    }
```

Define response inside the for loop..

Answer (score 0):

Everytime when invocation happens, though the response values are as expected, the formal parameters are replaced by actual parameters and the duplicated keys of responseList are replaced by the current value(last iteration). Defining response within the loop solves the problem.

```
    for(int i=0; i< nlist.size(); i++){
    HashMap<String,String> response = new HashMap<String,String>();
    response.put("Name",nlist.get(i));
    response.put("Age",alist.get(i));
    responseList.add(response);
    }
```